# Long request blocks other requests in Apache and PHP

Tags: php, apache

I have a request that takes about 1.5 minutes to complete, but when it does the request, it blocks all the other requests by the server. I'm using Apache with mod_php. What's the best way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: 1.5 minutes is really a long time for a single request.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<sub>[mod_telepathy]</sub>

Do you use sessions? If so - while you haven't closed session in long script, others will wait for it.

If you don't need session there all the time - you can close it with `session_write_close()`

<sub>[/mod_telepathy]</sub>

Comment: And by "others" it means "others from the same client". :)

Comment: @Ali Foroughi: ask another question

Comment: @zerkms , I want to ask to look at my question too,  thanks http://stackoverflow.com/q/11791911/985084

Answer (score 1):

File based Sessions will cause blocking. If you use a database or memcache/redis you can prevent this blocking.

Comment: This is plain wrong. Sessions are blocked until they get serialized and closed, no matter which file-handler you have defined.