# Multiple Jquery AJAX calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page where I'm trying to use Jquery's `$.get()` to make a call to a long running import script. In this script it updates a database with how far through the process it is `(i.e. 2%, 4% etc)`. I have another `$.get()` call (to check on the progress) which is setup through a setTimeout before the first `$.get()` is fired.

The problem I'm having is the `$.get()` call to check on progress never returns until the long running import `$.get()` returns. This doesn't seem to be right as they should be async.

As far as I can see the "check progress" URL is hanging if I launch it in a new tab within firefox, but if I load this in Chrome it returns instantly. As far as I know firefox should be able to run more than 1 AJAX call per hostname without a problem.

In Chrome with the developer tools enabled I see the "check progress" URL call as "pending" until the first one completes.

How can I get both requests to run async?

Comment: Scientific guess: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6405685/251311

Comment: Bingo, that was the problem. I was looking in the wrong place. If you add this as an answer I'll mark this question as closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use sessions? If so - while you haven't closed session in long script, others will wait for it.

If you don't need session there all the time - you can close it with `session_write_close()`

<sub>It's a complete copy of my other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6405685/251311</sub>