# Polling Apache server not responding

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, apache, loops

The apache server I am using to develop my system will not respond to request while the scripts that control the polling of messages is being run. This only happends on a domain level meaning that I can send an http request to any other apps hosted localy and get a response. When I do eventually get a response from this its about a minute later.

Here is the Js

```
window.fetch_messages = function ()
{
    var last_message = $("div.message:last").attr('data-ai_id');
    var last_message_status = $("p.message_status:last").text();
    var project_id = getParameterByName('project-id');

    $.ajax({
            url:'/project_messages',
            type:'POST',
            data:{ project_id:project_id, latest_message:last_message, status:last_message_status },
            timeout:50000,
            async: true,
            success:new_messages, // This upon completion also resends the request
            error:function(data){ console.log(data); setTimeout(fetch_messages(),50000); }
    });

}; // When On the page that uses this I call this function to start polling
```

Here is the server side code

```
do 
{
    // Check for status change
    $status_change = $this->mentor_model->query_status($this->project_id, $this->last_message_id, $this->last_message_status, $_SESSION['user']); 

    // Check for new messages
    $messages = $this->mentor_model->query_messages($this->project_id, $this->last_message_id); 

    // If there is a  status update or new message.
    if($messages || $status_change)
    break;

    usleep(1000000);
}
while(empty($messages) && empty($status_change));

echo json_encode(array("messages"=>$messages, "status"=>$status_change));
exit;
```

While this action is being run The server takes a long time to handle any request weather it be a GET, POST or another AJax request. Iv also tried changing both code sets to no avail as long as its long polling, the server will take a long time to handle.

Do I have this wrong or is there some apache setting I'm suppose to change. Using xamp on windows 8.1 also tried wamp with no change

Comment: usleep(1000000);?????

Comment: @steven that should make the script rest for a second before going over the loop again. To save cpu, mysql some work. I tried commenting it out makes no difference as I still wont get a response to any other requests unless this scrip has something to return in which case all other request go thru immediately

Comment: hmmm maybe something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405658/long-request-blocks-other-requests-in-apache-and-php

Comment: @steven You are without a doubt my best friend in the world RN.I Am forever in your debt THANK YOU SOOO MUCH :-)

Comment: easy. Your own answer is great so i don't need to write one.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to steven for this. Ansewer taken straight from the source of php manual page
for session_write_close();

> You can have interesting fun debugging anything with sleep() in it if
>   you have a session still active.  For example, a page that makes an
>   ajax request, where the ajax request polls a server-side event (and
>   may not return immediately).
>
> If the ajax function doesn't do session_write_close(), then your outer
>   page will appear to hang, and opening other pages in new tabs will
>   also stall.